# NiFi SelectHiveQL - Stop serving to incoming request

Tags: apache-nifi

Do anyone know why the SelectHiveQL processor is always stuck and not serving/responding to the incoming request. It happens only if the flow was ideal for some time.

I was able to retain the operation only when I do stop-start the processor also enable and disable the service manually.

As it is the dev environment I can do this manually, but I am more worried about if the same scenario happened in production.

Is there any way to solve this issue or anything which I need to change in my setup.

Appreciated your help in advance.

Comment: Which version of NiFi is this?

Comment: I observed the same in both the version 1.5 and now on 1.7 also.